# Reverse List<List<Integer>> using Collection

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I reverse a List of List using Collection?

Example: `[ [5], [10,15], [20,2] ]` to be `[ [20,2], [10,15], [5] ]`

So I have:

```
public List<List<Integer>> levelOrderBottom(TreeNode root){
   List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
   Queue<TreeNode> Q = new LinkedList<>();
   ... add stuff in Q
   result.add(nodes);
   return Collections.reverse(result); // what I want to do but its ArrayList<List> not ArrayList
}
```

I know I can do `result.add(0, nodes)` to add it to the front of the ArrayList, but I would like to solve this issue using Collection

Thank you

This is my error:

```
Line 36: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to List<List<Integer>>
    return Collections.reverse(result);
```

Comment: *its ArrayList<List> not ArrayList* what did you mean by this

Comment: @YCF_L that Collection.reverse argument is a List (ArrayList) and not a List<List>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Collection* class can't do this. But the class *Collection**s***. See [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)).

In your case:

```
Collections.reverse(result);
return result;
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a typo in the return statement.
The return `Collection.reverse(result);` should be
`Collections.reverse(result);`. It does not return anything. It reverses the list in-place and return void.
Link to the documentation for further reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I didn't check what the return was.